# How to crop regions of interest in an image using bounding box coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask, bounding-box

I have several grayscale images, each image having multiple regions of interests, in the form of rectangular bounding boxes. These multiple bounding box coordinates for the images are stored in a CSV file. I wish to multiply these bounding boxes with their respective images so that I have only the regions of interests left behind. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage import io
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_fill_holes
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import cv2

#get mask coordinates
def get_mask(img_name, df, h, w):
    im_csv_np = df.loc[:,"patientId"].values
    idx = np.where(im_csv_np == img_name)
    if idx[0].shape[0]: 
        mask = np.zeros((len(idx[0]),h,w))
        for k,j in enumerate(idx[0]):
            i = j.item()
            mask[k,int(df.loc[i]['y_dis']):int(df.loc[i]['y_dis'])+int(df.loc[i]['height_dis']),
                        int(df.loc[i]['x_dis']):int(df.loc[i]['x_dis'])+int(df.loc[i]['width_dis'])] = 1.0
    else:
        mask = np.zeros((1,h,w))
    return mask

#read data
filenames = glob.glob("data/*.png")
filenames.sort()
df1 = pd.read_csv('bbox.csv')

for f in filenames:
    img = cv2.imread(f, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    h,w = img.shape
    img_name = f.split(os.sep)[-1]
    print(img_name)
    mask1 = get_mask(img_name, df1, h, w)
    for i in range(len(mask1)):
        props = regionprops(mask1[i].astype(np.int8))[0]
        df_csv = {"patientId": img_name,
                  "x_dis": props.bbox[1],
                  "y_dis": props.bbox[0],
                  "width_dis": abs(props.bbox[3]-props.bbox[1]),
                  "height_dis": abs(props.bbox[2]-props.bbox[0])}
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask1[i].astype(np.uint8), 
                                       cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        for contour in contours:
            cropped_image = 
            ......
            ......
    
    io.imsave(os.path.join("bbox",
                           f.split(os.sep)[-1][:-4]+'.png'), cropped_image)
```

I need assistance with multiplying the images and bounding boxes and saving the ROI images.

Comment: I am a bit unsure about the `multiplying the images and bounding boxes and saving the ROI images`? Do you have the bounding box coordinates in the `(x, y, w, h)` format? Or you have them as a mask 2D matrix. Can you please add a little demonstration if possible ?

Comment: @ZdaR: All bounding box coordinates are available in (x, y, w, h) format. There may be multiple bounding boxes for any given image.

Comment: Ok, so imagine an image with 2 bounding boxes, one at the top left while other at the bottom right, so in this case how would you define the expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR: let's assume the top left box spans (10,10, 20, 30) and the bottom right spans (200,200,10,10). The resulting image should contain the original image pixel values only in these regions. Basically, these bounding box masks can be filled with "white" pixels and so when multiplied only these regions will remain and the rest blacked out.

Comment: Got it. So where are you exactly facing the problem? in csv parsing or multiplying the images?

Comment: @ZdaR: I need assistance with multiplying the images and bounding boxes and saving the ROI images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find contours. You already have the bbox information.
Try this:

```
for f in filenames:
    img = cv2.imread(f, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    h,w = img.shape
    img_name = f.split(os.sep)[-1]
    print(img_name)
    mask1 = get_mask(img_name, df1, h, w)
    for i in range(len(mask1)):
        props = regionprops(mask1[i].astype(np.int8))[0]
        
        cropped_image = img[props.bbox[0]:props.bbox[2],props.bbox[1]:props.bbox[3]]
    
        io.imsave(os.path.join("bbox",
                           f.split(os.sep)[-1][:-4]+'_'+str(i)+'.png'), cropped_image)
```

Comment: The code works. But it is cropping only one bounding box per image. Actually, there are multiple bounding boxes in a given image. So, for example, for an image named "image1.png" having say three bounding boxes, I should save these cropped bounding boxes as "image1_bb1.png", image1_bb2.png", and "imgae1_bb3.png".

Comment: Probably its overwriting the saved image. Insert index 'i' in your imsave. Look for the edits